# Firebase retrieve child via $id in $routeParams

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use the URL to pass information from my list to detail view. My URL contains the Firebase id. I did manage to retrieve the id, but I can't find how to read the corresponding record in Firebase.

I am having a list of bottles, and when I click on a bottle, I want to display its name.

*bouteilles.js*

```
angular.module('myApp.bouteilles', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/bouteilles', {
    templateUrl: 'bouteilles/bouteilles.html',
    controller: 'BouteillesCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('BouteillesCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  $scope.bouteilles = $firebaseArray(ref);

}]);
```

Then I have a list of "bouteilles" : 
*bouteilles.html*

```
<div class = "list" ng-repeat="bouteille in bouteilles>
  <a class="item item-avatar" href="#!/maBouteille/{{bouteille.$id}}">
    <h2>{{bouteille.name}} - {{bouteille.year}}</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

So that I have the bottle id in the URL. It is working OK since I can see in the log the id from *maBouteille.js*

```
angular.module('myApp.maBouteille', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/maBouteille/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'maBouteille/maBouteille.html',
    controller: 'MaBouteilleCtrl'
    });
}])

.controller('MaBouteilleCtrl', ['$routeParams','$scope','$firebaseArray', function($routeParams, $scope, $firebaseArray) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  console.log($routeParams.id);   
}]);
```

I can't figure out how I can use this $routeParams.id to retrieve the corresponding record in Firebase. Any idea?

Comment: you will get complete object in bouteille object in ng repeat.why again you want to fetch @fabien

Comment: In MaBouteilleCtrl, I would like to find data from the bottle clicked before

Comment: what is your node name??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.controller('MaBouteilleCtrl', ['$routeParams','$scope','$firebaseArray',     function($routeParams, $scope, $firebaseArray) {
     var ref = firebase.database().ref('your Node or table name'); //that node ref
         ref.child($routeParams.id).on("value",function(snapshots){ //value of that id
         console.log(snapshots.val()); //printing object
      })
  console.log($routeParams.id);   
}]);
```

here I am using angular js and firebase.

Comment: Thanks Ankit. I can see it in the log! However, I am still struggling to display it in my html...

Comment: I created a function extractData(test), calling it just below the console.log, but it's not working. {{name}} does not retrieve the name. Any idea how to terminate the job?

  function extractData(name){
    console.log("Name:" + name);
    $scope.name = name;
  }

Comment: I found it!     $('#name').append(snapshots.val().name); in the function and <div id="name></div> in the html. Thanks Ankit